# What needs to be changed in this archiving script to only archive specific file types?

Tags: command-line, compression, archiving, vbscript

I made this script based on past answers from superuser, but now need to only archive specific file types. I messed around trying to use wildcards but nothing I tried seemed to stick.

If I wanted to change this script to filter by specific file-types instead of all file system objects, what needs to be changed and how? For example, if I wanted to only archive DLL files, or DLL & EXE files, how would it be changed?

```
'To use this at command-line, call `CScript.exe zip_it.vbs SourceDirectory PathToOutputZipFileIncludingDotZipExt`
Set parameters = WScript.Arguments
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SourceDir = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(parameters(0))
ZipFile = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(parameters(1))
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source_objects = shell.NameSpace(SourceDir).Items
shell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source_objects)
wScript.Sleep 400
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter. The magic is here:

```
SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = 64
colFolderItems.Filter SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, "*.ext"
```

Here it is in context with your code:

```
'To use this at command-line, call `CScript.exe zip_it.vbs SourceDirectory PathToOutputZipFileIncludingDotZipExt "file.pattern"`
Set parameters = WScript.Arguments
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SourceDir = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(parameters(0))
ZipFile = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(parameters(1))
FileFilter = parameters(2)
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source_objects = shell.NameSpace(SourceDir).Items
SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = 64
source_objects.Filter SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, FileFilter
shell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source_objects)
wScript.Sleep 400
```

This can be called with "*.txt" to select only text files, or "*.exe" to collect only exe files. Also note that it doesn't play well if there is no file filter included.

However, your code is designed to recreate the ZIP each time, so you'd need to test for the existence of the file first if you want to call repeatedly for additional file types. This change does that:

```
If Not FS.FileExists (ZipFile) Then
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
End If
```

This does have a side-effect of popping (and almost immediately hiding) an overwrite prompt if the files already exist in the zip file. With that change you could do this:

```
cscript //nologo zip_it.vbs thefolder thefile.zip "*.txt"
cscript //nologo zip_it.vbs thefolder thefile.zip "*.doc"
```

It could be changed to iterate file types or extensions and collect all files if there is no filter, as so:

```
'To use this at command-line, call `CScript.exe zip_it.vbs SourceDirectory PathToOutputZipFileIncludingDotZipExt "file.pattern" "file2.pattern"`
Set parameters = WScript.Arguments
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SourceDir = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(parameters(0))
ZipFile = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(parameters(1))
SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = 64

If Not FS.FileExists (ZipFile) Then
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
End If

Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

If parameters.Count > 2 Then
    For lParams = 2 to (parameters.Count-1)
        FileFilter = parameters(lParams)
        Set source_objects = shell.NameSpace(SourceDir).Items
        source_objects.Filter SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, FileFilter
        shell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source_objects)
        wScript.Sleep 400
    Next
Else
    Set source_objects = shell.NameSpace(SourceDir).Items
    shell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source_objects)
    wScript.Sleep 400
End If
```

This could be called like:

```
cscript //nologo zip_it.vbs thefolder thefile.zip "*.doc" "*.txt"
```

Comment: I like your changes, but unfortunately as-written it's falling a little short. For one, it can only handle file-filters if that specific file-type exists directly in the source directory sent as the parameter. For another, even if it does, it won't find any in sub-directories. Interestingly enough, neither of our scripts seem to handle huge directories recursively; only small ones which is distressing! I didn't realize mine was so weak :(

Comment: There are other items in the enumeration that might allow you to filter using parameters that more accurately represent your needs. The [_SHCONTF enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_shcontf) supports 13 different values, and SHCONTF_FLATLIST or SHCONTF_CHECKING_FOR_CHILDREN might do what you're after.

Comment: I tried a lot of combinations, but could never get sub-directories zipping too. All I did was make a directory with a text file, then made another directory and put a text file in that. Both were populated with some data. If the combo even included an item, it would only be one of the two items. If you're able to get that use-case working, I will accept this answer so long as it isn't a cheesy hack (eg, sub-sub directories not working xD)

Comment: My answer above does answer the question you asked. You didn't mention subdirectories, you specifically asked for file types. The Folder object (created by the shell.Namespace() lines) represents a *specific* folder. It does not represent each *child* folder or the child items within those child folders, which is why the filter method only checks the current Items collection for matches.

Comment: To filter items within the subdirectories you'll need to alter the code to recurse into child folders using IsFolder/GetFolder and check each child item with another Filter. Be aware that doing it this way will require you to manually recreate the directory structure within the zip (which works fine with NewFolder, btw) though, since CopyHere doesn't preserve Parent objects.

Comment: You should also be careful of junction points when you recurse into the Items to check for folders. Stuff like AppData can exist within a subdirectory of itself, so consider excluding stuff that is both hidden & system.

Comment: While I understand how my question was worded, my original script above can handle sub-directories, so expecting yours to handle them too IMO is not an unreasonable expectation for the answer.

Comment: Have you tried creating a recursive method using the Filter function as explained and demonstrated above to traverse the subdirectories or do you expect someone else to write all the code for you?

Comment: Hey shawn; this is your answer to my question. I'm not trying to twist your arm, just improve the quality of the answer. Feel free to leave it as-is.

Comment: The point I made above is simply that the original script doesn't iterate into each child of that folders children. It iterates only the CURRENT folder object - meaning the current folder file and folders. This means that while a Filter will work on the current directory, each child folder would need to be parsed and filtered separately. If you are not concerned about filtering within the child folders you can use SHCONTF_FOLDERS to backup the entire contents of each folder, and the SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS to backup only matching files within the current folder.